# Working with Lists results in unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, list, 2d, collision-detection

## What

I am trying to write a system which includes the use of lists to manage objects other objects can interact with in various ways. In particular, I am working on collision detection for a 2d game. My issue is that the system I have divised is working strangely, in ways that I cannot identify. My eyes have been looking at this problem for hours now and they are getting sore, so I am looking for support here.

## Get to the point

Here is the issue: An object added before another object in the list cannot be interacted with, if this is done, the game simply crashes, telling me I cannot use the memory in the location of the former object. I could be wrong, but my understanding of Lists leads me to believe that this should not be the case, I should be able to access any data in any location of a list, right?

Interacting with the object added last to the list works perfectly fine, there is no issue, when that object is later removed from the list, the former object can then be interacted with perfectly fine, and so on.

## Show us the details

Here is the code to add objects to the lists, it is called every frame because the Lists clear themselves every frame as to keep their data up to date.

```cs
for (var k = 0; k < player.leftEmitter.projectiles.Count; k++) {
    var projectile = player.leftEmitter.projectiles[k];
    var targets = projectile.collider.targets;

    if (!testNPC.disposed) targets.Add(testNPC.collider);
    if (!testNPC2.disposed) targets.Add(testNPC2.collider);
}

for (var l = 0; l < player.rightEmitter.projectiles.Count; l++) {
    var projectile = player.rightEmitter.projectiles[l];
    var targets = projectile.collider.targets;

    if (!testNPC.disposed) targets.Add(testNPC.collider);
    if (!testNPC2.disposed) targets.Add(testNPC2.collider);
}
```

Here is the code called when interacting with the object, it is also called every frame.

```cs
for (var i = 0; i < targets.Count; i++) {
    var box = targets[i];

    if (!box.parent.disposed) {
        if (colliderRect.GetGlobalBounds().Intersects(box.colliderRect.GetGlobalBounds()) && !hasEntered) {
            hasEntered = true;
            OnColliderEnter(box);
        } else if (!colliderRect.GetGlobalBounds().Intersects(box.colliderRect.GetGlobalBounds()) && hasEntered) {
            hasEntered = false;
            OnColliderExit(box);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, simply checking to see if the target collider was disposed or not before iterating on its `OnColliderEnter()` function completely fixed the issue. In fact this has nothing to do with Lists, nor my understanding of them. It was simply that I did not handle disposal properly. I appreciate C#'s garbage collector, but sometimes it is difficult to remember to check everywhere for simple things like this.